# Error getting get_header when file is called from another php file

Tags: php, wordpress

I have file called *viewProfile.php*

```
<?php
get_header(); ?>

    //some code

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

which is working fine when used in a template.

When it is called after successful login from another file as

```
$path=get_stylesheet_directory_uri()."/viewProfile.php";
header("Location: $path");
```

> getting error as `Call to undefined function get_header()`

Comment: That's because you're loading `viewProfile.php` directly, and out of WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `wp-blog-header.php` file to initiate all the `WP` functions in newly created file.

```
require('../../wp-blog-header.php');
```